# SQL Replace entire row with value

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a row in a table which contains 300 randomly generated hashes. I would like to replace all of them with one specific hash. How could I write a query that replaces every value in said table with my specific hash? Right now my query looks like:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Hash]
    FROM [x].[y].[z]
```

X/Y/Z are different in my query obviously. However I do not know how I can then replace every value in the top 1000 Hashes with my specific hash.

Comment: Do you want to replace the Hash of every row in the table, or just the top 1000?

Comment: There are 1000 hashes specifically, so both would equal all of them. But yes all of them, could I use an UPDATE statement? What would the syntax look like if I did?

Comment: And are you sure this is mysql, `TOP` is sql server.

Comment: My mistake, this is SQL and not MySQL, I meant to tag sql-server instead of mysql. I will change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE [x].[y].[z]
SET Hash = 'OneHashToRuleThemAll'
```

No `WHERE` condition will update the entire table.  Make sure this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use self inner join to update just the top 1000, like below. Note that I replaced TOP with LIMIT since we are talking about MySQL

```
UPDATE [x].[y].[z] XYZ
INNER JOIN 
 (
  select SOME_KEY_FROM_XYZ from [x].[y].[z] LIMIT 1000
 ) ZYX ON XYZ.SOME_KEY_FROM_XYZ = ZYX.SOME_KEY_FROM_XYZ
SET Hash = 'OneSpecificHash'
```